# toString() implementation for Array

Tags: arrays, offset, tostring

Before I state my question, I would like to thank everyone who helped me on my previous question. Anywho, I am currently getting the memory offsets as result even when I place it to the to a toString method. I've read most of the questions regarding the toString method and have somewhat of a understanding, I just wanted to make sure if I'm implementing this correctly. If you feel that this is a redundant question, I understand. Thanks for the help in advance.

Ship class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ship{

    int type;
    public String [][] shipPiece = new String[11][11];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Coordinate xy = new Coordinate();
    //private Coordinate[] bawdPiece = {new section()};
public Ship(){

}
    public String[][] placeShip()
    {
       System.out.println();
       for(int x = 1; x<10; x++)
       {
           for(int y = 1; y<10; y++)
           {
               shipPiece[x][y] = "0";
               System.out.print("|" + shipPiece);
           }
       }
       return shipPiece;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

        temp.append(shipPiece);
        return temp.toString();
    }
```

Comment: you can't use .append on a 2D array of strings. You have to loop over shipPiece array and add each item individually.

Comment: So I keep my array in the loop but I dont use a toString method? Sorry if im not getting a full grasp onto this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
       for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
       {
          temp.append(String.valueOf(shipPiece[x][y]);
       }
       temp.append("\n");
    }

    return temp.toString();
}
```

Also another thing I would like to point out is your array initialization. You initialize it with 11 x 11 indices, but your loop is only adding 9 values to each row and column Loop starts at 1 and ends at 9. You may want to fix your initialization to 10 x 10 and make your loop start at 0.

Comment: I wouldn't need the String[][] placeShip() method wouldnt I?

Comment: Well, the method you are talking about fills the array. If you don't fill it, all the values will be null, Maybe just have the method return void and take out the print statements. The method will just be used to initialize the values of the array. Also I made a change to my toString method. It was incorrect.

Comment: Okay, It seemed to fixed the memory offset, I think. But it isnt displaying the array.

Comment: Did you call the `placeShip` before you tried and call the `toString()`? If the placeShip is not called, the array will have no values.

Comment: You need to make sure all shipPiece indices have values.

Comment: Sorry i didnt answer earlier I didnt have internet, but I have it returning a 'toString()' and called it from my player class 'sh.shipPiece.toString()' but im still unable to see anything

Comment: All you need to do is `Ship sh = new Ship(); sh.placeShip(); System.out.println(sh);`

Comment: Thanks alot skillet. I've have been looking for a way to have it display it for hours but that line did it for me. Once again thanks :D

Comment: The whole point over the `toString()` is to override the `toString()` of the Object superclass. You can just print the object `sh` without overriding the method, and you'll get come weird return, So if you override the method as you have, you can print the object and have it print the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to get the index of the shipPiece as a string?

If that's the case try `String.ValueOf(index)`, you'll obviously have to do this twice as you have a 2-dimensional array.

Ex:

```
String s = String.ValueOf(xIndex) + "," + String.ValueOf(yIndex);
```

Comment: Yes, let me try that and I'll get back with you. won't take long.

Comment: About that, will I have to have each piece added on individually?Taking both yours and Red Alerts idea in consideration.

Comment: You'll have to loop through each piece of the ship I think. Depends what you want to display when you say myShip.toString()